# Why does custom Estimator end up overriding Nothing type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am implementing a custom estimator which has troubles accessing a parameter `ava.util.NoSuchElementException: Failed to find a default value for isInList`. It is defined as follows:

```
trait PreprocessingParams extends Params {
  final val isInList = new Param[Array[String]](this, "isInList", "list of isInList items")
}
```

To better debug the problem I created a minimal example here https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/8dc7a6b6938a517f068e7fd6a981ed12 the `ExampleTrans` works just fine. However, I would rather like to include the functionality of the transformer into an estimator which performs some data cleaning as well.

But now I face strange compile issues `overriding method has wrong type - expecting Nothing`

What is wrong with the return types of my `ExampleEstimator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify the generic types of `Estimator` type constructor and so `Nothing` has been used instead.

Use:

```
class ExampleEstimator(override val uid: String) 
  extends Estimator[ExampleTransModel] with PreprocessingParams {
  ...
}
```

The full definition of [Estimator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator) is as follows:

```
abstract class Estimator[M <: Model[M]] extends PipelineStage
```

Note the generic type `M` that extends Model.